# psmouse sync issues

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, input, touchpad

I have Compaq CQ61-420US (64-bit AMD) laptop with Synaptics touchpad checked using

```
$ egrep -i 'synap' /proc/bus/input/devices
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
```

But recently after *Arch Linux 3.15-1 stock kernel*, I have a lot of these messages in my dmesg accompanied with **mouse freezes**:

```
[    7.064589] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 6.5, id: 0x1c0b1, caps: 0xa04751/0xa00000/0x0, board id: 3655, fw id: 428212
[11981.973831] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[11981.975792] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[11981.977503] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[11981.986308] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[11981.988072] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[11981.988084] psmouse serio1: issuing reconnect request
```

And after I remove and reinstall psmouse through modprobe as mentioned here on the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Touchpad_synchronization_issues)

```
# modprobe -r psmouse ; modprobe psmouse
```

I get in dmesg:

```
[12012.349197] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 6.5, id: 0x1c0b1, caps: 0xa04751/0xa00000/0x0, board id: 3655, fw id: 428212`
```

Even though the mouse starts working, but even a short amount of inactivity it gets disabled, and I have this every now and then... sad

Also I downgraded synaptics & evdev to previous versions as of now.  I also tried using:

```
# modprobe -r psmouse
# modprobe psmouse proto=imps
# sudo modprobe psmouse proto=bare
```

but none of them work.

I also tried changing the CPU governor to USERSPACE which was originally PERFORMANCE, no luck even then.

P.S: I also posted my problem on [ArchLinux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=184067).

Comment: You're definitely not alone! I'm on Lubuntu 14.04.1 here and lo and behold, I'm not on a notebook but on a desktop PC! Well, I think this must have gotten introduced with the 14.04->14.04.1 update. It's extremely annoying and a pointless (though typical) answer like "use an usb mouse" won't help me much, since I have an older machine and I do need my USB ports! I don't want to occupy it with a mouse if I don't absolutely have to.

Comment: @syntaxerror Check my ArchLinux thread(mentioned in post) there a kinda all the possible workarounds present in it maybe some might help you!!

Comment: yes, thanks, checked this out already. However, there is still no information about the actual cause of this. If this doesn't stop, we'll have to inform the guys from [LKML](http://lkml.org) eventually. This is _absolutely unbearable_ for daily work.

Comment: @syntaxerror The problem is I really don't know whether it is a synaptics driver problem or a psmouse problem and if did post it on LKML without contacting the driver author first, they did burn me!! Thanks though!!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the following boot parameters?

```
i8042.reset i8042.nomux=1 psmouse.proto=imps
```

Had a similar problem on my laptop and the problem went away with those parameters.

Comment: Oh, This problem was solved after Linux 3.17.x (eventhough problem exist in 3.16 LTS), and also imps kills all trackpad functionality(there is scrolling available though), however in power-save and conservative governors the problem persists!! Thanks for replying though!